# Outlook HTML signature with external text

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, html, email-signature

The company I work for has implemented new signatures to be used with Outlook 2010. Our company is also present at many exhibitions a year, and we would like to let our clients know just that.

The problem is that I want to load an external text file in our html signatures, so that I only need to update one file that contains the information on the exhibitions we'll be attending.

Outlook strips iframe tags, object tags and it seems I am unable to run php scripts as well.

Can anyone help me find an alternative?

Comment: Are you familiar with VBA?

Comment: Not quite, but I can always look for an ad hoc solution

Comment: Take a look at default.htm (may be another name on your machine) on `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures` (The default location where Outlook stores the signatures). The HTML is kinda messy, but I think that you can make a script to update it